# thymeleaf text mode string how to keep indent for each line

Tags: html, thymeleaf

i have a string stored in database which contains line break, it should looks like following when displaying on page:

```
abc
def
hkg
```

now i need to add this string to an email dialog as email content and its format should be:

[image]

my thymeleaf text template to generate email content looks like:

```
Test: [# th:each="g : ${gList}"]    
    Description:
        [(${g.descr})]
```

However, after i added the template content to a `textarea`, it is:
[image]

that is there is no indent from line 2, this is not what i want.

how can i get the format like following for one string which contains multiple lines?

```
Test:
    Description:
        abc
        def
        hkg
```

The html code to show the email content in dialog is :

```
<div class="row">                       
    <label class="col-2 text-right">Content:</label>
    <textarea id="emailContent" class="col-9" v-model="email.content" >
    </textarea>
</div>
```

another question is : what if this string is long but no line break, it only has spaces between words. in this case, it still display the rest of this string from line 2 without indent.

Comment: Assuming your e-mail's content type is "text/html" (i.e. not plain text), try adding the CSS style `white-space: pre;` to the enclosing tag. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: @andrewjames did u mean `<textarea style="white-space:pre"`, i tried but not worked.

Comment: Yes - that is what I meant (works for me). Must be some other difference.

Answer (score 0):

The string stored in the database is `abc\ndef\nhkg` therefore when you print it out you are getting:

```
Test:\n
....Description:\n
........abc\n
def\n
hkg
```

Since this is plain text and you don't have any of the formatting capabilities of html, you're going to have to modify the string itself.  Basically, you need to replace your newlines `\n` with 8 spaces and a new line.  You want the string to look like:

```
abc\n........def\n........hkg
```

As for what that looks like in Thymeleaf.  Kind of ugly, but I think this should work for you:

```
Test: [# th:each="g : ${gList}" th:with="newline=${T(System).getProperty('line.separator')}"]    
    Description:
        [(${#strings.replace(g.descr, newline, newline + '        ')})]
```

Comment: this is one option, and how about if this string is long and no line break, only has space? and when some of it need to be displayed on line 2, it still shown without indent on line 2.